# Sleep Function Calls in Relation to Mutex Locks

Tags: java, c++, multithreading, mutex, sleep

I'm trying to get a better grasp on using sleep function calls in relation to mutex locks.  If a mutex were to be held by one thread while the sleep from another thread expires, does control go back to the first thread immediately, or would the thread have to at least wait for the mutex being held to be released first before switching back to the other thread?

Comment: This is tagged both `java` and `c++`. The details will differ. Do you want to know about both, or just one?

Comment: In java the method sleep has nothing to do with mutex. It's a method like any other, perhaps you wanted to say something like the method await

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom yes, I do want to know about about both,

Answer (score 3):

There is no relationship between `Thread.sleep()` and any kind of lock.

A call to `Thread.sleep(nnn)` returns after at least `nnn` milliseconds have elapesed (unless it throws an InterruptedException), and that's all a developer ever needs to know about it.

Pretty much all you need to know about mutexes (e.g., `synchronized` blocks), is that only one thread can lock the same instance at the same time time.  A locked mutex becomes available to waiting threads as soon as the owner unlocks it.  It has nothing to do with whether or not any of the threads is or was in a `sleep()` call.

Comment: And (apart from trivial differences like function names and the non-existance of `synchronized` blocks), this applies equally well to C++.